# How to upload and download any file from CQ DAM/repository through JAVA code

Tags: java, aem

I am new to CQ5.4 and having hands on in content zipper and content loader module of CQ. How can we do the same through any JAVA Code?

Thanks
Rishi

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking, but you ought to be able to use a tool like Fiddler to inspect the requests that go out to the CQ server, and re-create those with your Java code.